# Modifying code to recive only RMC output in GPS

Tags: gps, nmea

I am using GPS module for my application. I want only the RMC data. So what am I supposed to do in my code to get only this data, i.e all the other formats like GGA,GSA,VTG should be disabled.

Please Help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable the other messages, and there is no reason to do so.  Some GPS units support commands to enable/disable messages, but it is anything but standard.

Simply use a `switch` statement in your code on the sentence identifying field, and have a `case` block for `GPRMC`.